# Does the order of the attributes in a projection impact the speed of execution of the SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, performance, projection

Lets say I have a table with columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I in that order, and I need to select only columns A, C, F, I (it could be the case that the table has many more columns and I have to retrieve many more columns too).

My question is, would it make a difference (performance wise) if I keep the order of the columns to be retrieved in the projection in ascending column index number (e.g A, C, F, I) rather than retrieving them at a complete random order (e.g. F, A, I, C). And why?

I understand that sequential access is faster than random access, however none of the cases in my example is sequential so I'm not sure what the performance difference of these two projection orders would be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: NO.

Long answer: it depends.

In general case, this question is impossible to answer without knowing which product you use.

**Ordering** of output columns should not matter.

In most row-based relational databases (including Microsoft, PostgreSQL and Oracle), ordering of output columns will make no visible difference. This is because row data is read from memory block-wise (in 8kB or 32kB chunks, for example). After reading into memory, processing is quite cheap.

**Number** of output columns can make a difference, especially in databases built with columnar (column-based) storage. Also with row-based storage this can matter (just because of in-memory processing cost and data transfer cost).

Please specify if you have particular database engine on your mind.

Answer (score 0):

The order by which you write columns in a SELECT statement SELECT A, B, C and SELEC B, A, C is exactly the same thing. It is absolutely irrelevant.

The one thing that matters is weather or not, if you are selecting only 3 columsn out of a gigantic table with 100 columns. If you have a composite non sparse index on columns A,B,C that the database engine could use to avoid doing a full row read.

If you hand an index on columns A,B,C that you are referring in the SELECT statement then potentially... the DB engine may decide the best thing to do is to execute an Index only plan without needing to load all the Bytes involved in a single DB row column of 100 columns.

With that said. 
The order by which you declared TABLES in a FROM clause is not at all Irrelevant.

You should normally name your tables in a FROM clause starting from the TABLES you believe to have more selective predicates for filtering data and by which you would yourself implemented nested loop joins.

I've seen DBs like HSQL whose DB engine optimize failed to use all the appropraite indexes I had created depending on the order by which I named the tables in the FROM clause.
That depends on how the DB query optimize is implemented and how many query execution plans it it will explore. Writeing tables in the appropriate order in the FROM clause will help you out.

Knowing how to plan indexes for tuning a query as well.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, would it make a difference (performance wise) if I keep the order of the columns to be retrieved in the projection in ascending column index number (e.g A, C, F, I) rather than retrieving them at a complete random order (e.g. F, A, I, C). And why?

Possibly, but it would be unlikely to be significant, and it will vary depending on implementation.  MySQL and SQL Server could easily have entirely different answers.

My understanding of SQL Server, for example, is that it reads the disk in fixed chunks called pages, which are 8 kilobytes in size.  With some exceptions for LOBs, a single row is not allowed to span more than one page, which creates the 8060 byte limit.  If your data would exceed that and you're not using LOBs, you'd actually have to create another table.  So, not matter what you do, when SQL Server reads a record from a table it's reading the entire page and therefore the entire record.

Now, there's a number of things that can alter what goes on.  Indexes that cover all your columns, sparse columns, LOBs, and so on will significantly alter how the data are stored and accessed in your tables.  But none of that is going to be affected by how you order things.  Part of the query engine's job is to determine the most efficient way to retrieve the data from disk.

**Bottom line:** I/O is going to orders of magnitude more costly than the ordering of those columns in memory.  Beyond a possible contrived example, I can't think of a reason that this would be a consideration for writing a query.